# How to JOIN three tables in BigQuery by a common column name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have three tables with the following relation.

t1 has program_id

t2 has program_id and product_name

t3 has product_name and price

t1

```
order_id|product_id|   program_id
  1     |        AA|          100
  2     |        BB|          110
  3     |        CC|          500
  4     |        DD|          550
```

t2

```
name    |program_id|    name
 mike   |       100|    1bx
 john   |       110|    2bx
 bob    |       500|    3bx
 clara  |       550|    3bx
 jane   |       112|    55x
```

t3

```
admin_id|product_name|revenue
  z1    |         1bx|    100
  z2    |         2bx|    110
  z3    |         3bx|    500
  z4    |         4bx|    550
```

My purpose here is to JOIN the first two tables and after that JOIN the result of the first JOIN with the third table.
In the end it should look something like:

t4

```
program_id|product_name|revenue
  z1      |         1bx|    100
  z2      |         2bx|    110
  z3      |         3bx|    500
  z4      |         4bx|    550
```

where t3 would give me the price for each program_id and product_name.
How could I efficiently join the third table with the result of the first Join?

Comment: So, what is the problem ?

Comment: can you please revisit your question - it does not make sense to me no matter from which angle I am trying to read it!

Comment: Yes I apologise for this.In my case t2 may contain program_id's that don't come from t1 but from another table.
Example:( jane   |       112|    55x)
I would like to identify only the program_id's that come from t1 and find the corresponding product_name in t2.
After that I would like to append the revenue from t3 to the result of the first join.
I can join t1 with t2 and t2 with t3 but not t1 with t3 directly.

Answer (score 1):

This just sounds like two `JOIN`s to me:

```
select program_id, product_name, revenue as price
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (program_id) join
     table3 t3
     using (product_name);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply...How would I join table t3 if the the column "product_name" would have same data but different column title in t3?

Comment: @ORCos . . . New questions should be asked as new *questions*.  This answers the question that you have asked here.